# Validating OpenCart password hash in ruby

Tags: php, ruby, opencart

I'm migrating a system from OpenCart to Spree in ruby, and as part of that I would like to seamlessly migrate the users so they can keep login in without changing their passwords.

Looking at the OpenCart code I've found the login function for the website. I'm not great at PHP, so I'm trying to understand how to reproduce the following in ruby

```
SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->db->escape($password) . "')))))
```

I've tried the following, with no success:

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}#{Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}#{Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(" . #{password . ")}")}")
```

My current test case is:

- Password: 7fe391813e
- Salt: e4e91e33a
- OpenCart hash (what I'm trying to get): 2e62a3b86da5ce878895bcc5745725493bde7ef0

Has anyone done the same migration before? Or can someone explain what the PHP code is actually doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenCart code is a MySQL statement, PHP is used only to construct it. You were close with your Ruby alternative, the problem was in password inclusion, dots are used only in PHP. Here is the correct one:

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}#{Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}#{Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)}")}")

irb(main):001:0> password = "7fe391813e"
=> "7fe391813e"
irb(main):002:0> salt = "e4e91e33a"
=> "e4e91e33a"
irb(main):005:0> Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}#{Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{salt}#{Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)}")}")
=> "2e62a3b86da5ce878895bcc5745725493bde7ef0"
```